# Dust.js in IE8 "Object doesn't support property or method 'isArray'"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dust.js

I am passing in some Data to a javascript Dust template. I am getting this error in IE8 only:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'isArray' 
>   dust-full-1.2.0.js, line 628 character 34

There doesn't seem to be too much documentation/forums for dust but I have to use it for this client. I'm hoping it's not a problem with Dust but maybe just something that is in my code that isn't working with ie8. However, my attempts to debug this have produced no results.

Any ideas what this could relate to?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff848265(v=vs.94).aspx It says IE8 doesnt support isArray. This might be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `dustjs-1.2.0`.  I believe this was fixed in `dustjs-1.2.2`.  It doesn't say specifically, but `Array.isArray` was replaced by `dust.isArray` according to this issue on the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/pull/241

The most current version is at `2.0.2`, although the release notes stopped listing changes at `2.0.0`.

The Release Notes are just below the *Dust helpers - Code examples* section on this page:

http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/#dust-core-features---code-examples